# sklearnでのモデル再学習について

Tags: python, scikit-learn

現在Pythonのsklearnを用いて、機械学習を行っています。
モデルを作成し、そのモデルから予測をすることはできています。
そこで質問なのですが、このモデルを再度学習したい場合そのモデルを用いて
追加学習をすることはできるのでしょうか。
もしくは、以前学習に使用したデータを用いなければならないのでしょうか。
 基本的な質問かもしれませんがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/180650

Answer (score 1):

オンライン学習(またはインクリメンタル学習)と呼ばれる機能をscikit-learnのいくつかのモデルは実装しています。
https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning

オンライン学習を使えば、その都度追加の学習データで追加学習をすることができます。

scikit-learnの分類モデルにおいて、オンライン学習をサポートしているアルゴリズムは以下です:

- sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB
- sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB
- sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron
- sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier
- sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier

追加学習するためには、fitメソッドを呼び出すのと同じ要領で `partial_fit` メソッドを呼び出してください。

オンライン学習をサポートしていない機械学習アルゴリズムの場合は、前回訓練に使ったデータに追加のデータを加えた一つの巨大な訓練データを使って、`fit`メソッドによって一から訓練し直すことになります。